# Ошибка при команде git init в терминале VSCODE

Tags: git

Хочу залить проект в гитхаб. Работаю в терминале на VSCODE в папке с проектом прописываю команду git init, но выдаёт ошибку:

```
git : Имя "git" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а  
также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ git init
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Делаю это в первый раз и пошагово по видосу, но я не заметил, чтобы в нем(в видосе) подгружали какие то сторонние штуки, все прекрасно работает, подскажите где я налажал?

Comment: git хотябы установлен (+прописан в PATH)? попробуйте запустите git из cmd. работает?

Comment: Такая же ошибка. Помог перезапуск редактора Atom из которого запускал терминал

Comment: Прописан ли путь до git в PATH, можно узнать ничего не перезапуская.  Перезапуск программ, ПК и т.д. никогда не решают проблему, только отодвигают ее на будущее. Так что, ваш ответ не решает проблему ТС и является не более чем комментарием.

Answer (score 2):

Была такая же проблема,нашел в чем причина. Стоит по умолчанию в терминале Windows Powershell. Справа в терминале должен быть выпадающий список (скорее всего там будет написано 1.powershell) Нажимаешь туда и будет выбор,кликаешь на выбрать по умолчанию,дальше Git Bash и вуаля,всё работает)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала я установил [Git-2.33.0.2-64-bit.exe](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Затем я изменил переменные среды от VS Code: тогда заработало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитаты или документацию, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке] (/help/how-to-answer).